# Is there any way to override a setter property in extending class in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
class A {
    var selectedColor: Int
        get() = selectedColor
        set(selectedColor) {
            this.selectedColor = selectedColor
            doSomething()
        }
}

class B : A {
    override var selectedColor: Int
        get() = selectedColor
        set(selectedColor) {
            this.selectedColor = selectedColor
            doSomethingElse()
        }
}
```

the keyword override is showing error saying
'selectedColor' is final and cannot be overridden.
Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do that, you need to mark both `class A` and the property as `open` ([they are `final` by default](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance)):

Also, your getters are written as `get() = selectedColor` and setters have `this.selectedColor = selectedColor` assignments, which are actually both recursive calls to the same accessor, which will lead to `StackOverflowError`. To [access the value of the backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields), use `get() = field` and `field = ...` instead.

```
open class A {
    open var selectedColor: Int = someDefaultValue
        get() = field
        set(value) {
            field = value
            doSomething()
        }
}
```

Then you can `override` the property, and if you want the getter behavior to be unchanged, you can call `super.selectedColor`:

```
class B : A() {
    override var selectedColor: Int = someDefaultValue
        get() = super.selectedColor
        set(value) {
            field = value
            doSomethingElse()
        }
}
```

If you want to call the superclass's setter, use `super.selectedColor = value` instead of `field = value`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set your var selectedColor to open. I think it's good

like this :

```
class A {

open var selectedColor: Int
    get() = selectedColor
    set(selectedColor) {
        this.selectedColor = selectedColor
        doSomething()
    }
}
```

Comment: nice, If you want more explanation, look @hotkey's answer :)